# Can we get posts data using #hashtags from Linkedin

Tags: python, linkedin-api, posts, hashtag

I have extensively reviewed the documentation for API v2 and could not locate any references to hashtags. Therefore, I am curious to know if it is feasible to obtain public posts, from both individuals and companies, that are sorted using a particular keyword?

I have looked at linkedin forums and few other repositories, but couldn't get a satisfactory results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: by using likedin api   from linkedin_api import Linkedin